# How to disable slide to delete for a UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Does anybody know how to disable the 'slide-to-delete' in a uitableview?

I still want to be able to delete the rows while the table is in editing mode.

Comment: Did you ever consider excepting answers to your other questions?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Mine is:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   return self.editing ;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

First, to confirm if a table cell can be deleted simply reply to canEditRowAtIndexPath.

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  // Return YES or NO
  return(YES);
  }
}
```

Then, to actually delete the table cell reply to commitEditingStyle.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
  // Delete your data

  // Delete the table cell
  [self.tableView deleteRowAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
  }
}
```

Good luck Mats Stijlaart!

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: The first code sample let you disable swipe-to-delete. The second code sample let you delete a row when editing is active. I was sure it could help you... Regards

Comment: In the first block of code, it should be "BOOL" as return type instead of "void"

Comment: Thanks Chintan Patel I corrected the first block of code! rjobidon